# Как сделать правильный подсчёт количества фотографий в PagerAdapter?

Tags: android, android-studio, activity, android-viewpager

Как в titleBar сделать счётчик фотографий? А именно, получить значение текущей.

## PhotoActivity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

    assert actionBar != null;
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    List<View> pages = new ArrayList<View>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
         View photo = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_photo, null);
         ImageView imageView = (ImageView)photo.findViewById(R.id.ScrollImage);
         imageView.setImageDrawable(
                   new APIweb(PhotoActivity.this, false)
                   .ImageLoad("https://www.google.ru/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"));
        pages.add(photo);
    }

    PhotoAdapter pagerAdapter = new PhotoAdapter(pages, PhotoActivity.this);
    ViewPager viewPager = new ViewPager(this);
    viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);

    setContentView(viewPager);
}
```

Это вот #PhotoAdapter#

```
public class PhotoAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

Activity g_activity;
List<View> pages = null;

public PhotoAdapter(List<View> pages, Activity activity){
    this.pages = pages;
    g_activity = activity;
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position){
    View v = pages.get(position);
    ((ViewPager) collection).addView(v, 0);
    g_activity.setTitle("Фотогафий " + (position + 1) + " из " +this.getCount());
    return v;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(View collection, int position, Object view){
    ((ViewPager) collection).removeView((View) view);
}

@Override
public int getCount(){
    return pages.size();
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object){
    return view.equals(object);
}

@Override
public void finishUpdate(View arg0){
}

@Override
public void restoreState(Parcelable arg0, ClassLoader arg1){
}

@Override
public Parcelable saveState(){
    return null;
}

@Override
public void startUpdate(View arg0){
}
```

}

Дело в том что в адапетере в instantiateItem
position = не корректно считает количество фоток.

```
g_activity.setTitle("Фотогафий " + (position + 1) + " из " +this.getCount());
```

При перелистывании показывает либо 1 либо 3, перелистнёшь на второе фото счётчик покажет 3 из 3 хотя должно быть 2 из 3

### На скриншоте момент когда счётчик должен был показать 2 из 3

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решилось обработкой события в #PhotoActivity#

```
    PhotoAdapter pagerAdapter = new PhotoAdapter(pages, PhotoActivity.this);
    ViewPager viewPager = new ViewPager(this);
    viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

    setTitle("Фотография 1 из " + photo_count);

    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            setTitle("Фотография " + (position + 1) + " из " + photo_count);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset,
                                   int positionOffsetPixels) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Адаптер не предназначен для того/, чтобы знать, какая страница сейчас открыта во `ViewPager`. Для этого нужно использовать `OnPageChangedListener`

```
viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {}
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {}

    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        g_activity.setTitle("Фотогафий " + (position + 1) + " из " + viewPager.getAdapter().getCount() );
    }
});
```